# Not able to connect to EC2 instance from a different IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance that has an IPv4 filter for my IP Address only.  However, I'd like a friend of mine to get access (who lives in another city).  I currently maintain the IP Address filters on my management console.

I have UFW enabled (however, I limit UFW everywhere for the ssh port).

I added my friend's IP address in the AWS management console, but he's unable to access the server (we have checked all the pem files).

My questions:

1. Is there a limit on the number of IP addresses that I can enter using aws management console?
2. Is UFW clashing with management console here?
3. If I want to provide access to my friend, is there any other way (apart from VPN - We tried it, but we couldn't implement it)?

Comment: Could you please clarify your setup? Are the IP addresses configured in the Security Group associated with the EC2 instance, or in the firewall on the instance itself? If you are using both, could you try deactivating one to assist in debugging (eg turn off UFW to test the Security Group)?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein... Yes.  The IP Addresses are configured in my security group for the ec2 instance.  The UFW is there to only block the other ports.  This is my UFW Status for the ports: 22 limit (both in and out), 80 allow (in and out), 443 allow (in and out), 53 allow (out only).  Other ports have been blocked.  I will try deactivating UFW and pasting a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

So troubleshooting stuff

1: Ask your friend check is IP address again is that static or not . http://whatismyipaddress.com/

2: Ask him to test using telnet command

`telnet IPADDRESSOFSERVER 22`

3: Check you setting again on security group it should be like SSH open to `XX.XX.XX.XX/32` this is your friend IP address

let us know above results

Comment: He tried telnetting into the server.  He got "unable to connect to the remote host, connection refused".  We updated my security group with his ip address xx.xx.xx.xx/32

Comment: I'd suggest starting from first principles. Launch another EC2 instance with the same keypair, temporarily open port 22 to the world (`0.0.0.0/0`), confirm that you can login and then ask your friend to login. If it works, try restricting the security group to your friend's IP address and ask your friend to login again. If that works, you know the problem isn't at your friend's end. If it doesn't work, it might be because his IP address isn't what you think it is -- if they are going through a corporate network, web requests might have a different IP to SSH requests.